# Problem with deprecated constructor in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I use FPDM to autopopulate PDF documents by a simple script I got at
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php

I used it on my old server and it was working in PHP version: 5.6.30
But with a new server PHP version: 7.1.14

I get this error message
Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; FPDM has a deprecated constructor in home2/mysevername/public_html/FPDM/fpdm.php on line 51

Pleas advise

Comment: Go in and edit the library. Or find a whole new library that is updated. Specifically, you may only need to change `function FPDM() {` to `function __construct() {`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thankyou  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!